# ModalTrigger: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Update: I found that ModalTrigger has been deprecated: 1b1af04 [changed] deprecate

Now I am investigating this.

I am having trouble with react-bootstrap ModalTrigger. The following use to work but after upgrading to 
"react-bootstrap": "^0.25.1", 
"react": "^0.13.3",

I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Do you know why?

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {    
      super(props);
      this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    }

  close(){
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

    render() {

      var mymodal = ( 
        <Modal show={true} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h4>Text</h4>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      )

        return (
        <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <ModalTrigger key='modalinput' modal={mymodal}>

                  <Button style={buttonStyle}>
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </Button>

                </ModalTrigger>
              </th>
              <th>X</th>
              <th>Y</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>


          </tbody>
        </Table>
        );

    } // Render

  }; // Component
```

Comment: Did you check the upgrade docs for react-bootstrap to see if they changed the way the modal worked? I believe that error refers to trying to build a react component but the reference is undefined (ie Modal).

Comment: I just did :-) Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

ModalTrigger is deprecated, you now just use Modal: